# Animate a single word in a sentence with CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a single word in the middle of a sentence using CSS and HTML. I'm want the word to animate downward and fade out, as a new word fades in from above. My problem is that the rest of the sentence after the animating word isn't spacing correctly. As you can see below, the animating word is overlapping the rest of the sentence.

[image]

Here's a screencast of the animation: https://www.dropbox.com/s/svjrbqug3gjsg2s/movie.mov?dl=0

And here's my code so far:

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rotate.css">
</head>

<section class="rw-wrapper">

<span>The</span>
    <div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
        <span>inspiration</span>
        <span>accountability</span>
        <span>results</span>
        <span>community</span>
        <span>experience</span>
        <span>coaching</span>
    </div>
<span>you're looking for.</span>

</section>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.rw-wrapper{
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 110px auto 0 auto;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif';
    padding: 10px;
}
.rw-words{
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 2px;
}
.rw-words-1 span{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #6b969d;
    -webkit-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(2) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 3s; 
    animation-delay: 3s; 
    color: #6b969d;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(3) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s; 
    animation-delay: 6s; 
    color: #6b969d; 
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(4) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 9s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 9s; 
    animation-delay: 9s; 
    color: #6b969d;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(5) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s; 
    animation-delay: 12s; 
    color: #6b969d;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(6) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 15s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 15s; 
    animation-delay: 15s; 
    color: #6b969d;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    2% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); }
    5% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);}
    17% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    20% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    2% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(-30px); }
    5% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px);}
    17% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    20% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(30px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    2% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); transform: translateY(-30px); }
    5% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); transform: translateY(0px);}
    17% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); transform: translateY(0px); }
    20% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30px); transform: translateY(30px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .rw-sentence { font-size: 18px; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
    .rw-sentence { font-size: 9px; }
}
```

How can I use CSS to get the rest of my sentence to space properly for the animating word?

Comment: Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5dLdgor/) for anyone who wants to help find a solution.

Comment: Are you opposed to javascript for this?

Comment: I'd like to use CSS if possible.

Comment: Timothy Miller seems to have nailed it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this in pure CSS by animating the `max-width` of the individual spans. Here’s a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/tjacobdesign/pen/WvGXEZ), and here’s the CSS (prefixes removed for clarity. To get them back just click the little 'View Compiled' button on CodePen)

```
.rw-wrapper{
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 110px auto 0 auto;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif';
    padding: 10px;
}
.rw-words{
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: 2px;
}
.rw-words-1 span{
    max-width: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #6b969d;
    margin-left: -4px;
    animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 3s;
    color: #6b969d;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 6s; 
    color: #6b969d; 
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 9s; 
    color: #6b969d;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: 12s; 
    color: #6b969d;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(6) {
    animation-delay: 15s; 
    color: #6b969d;
}
@keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 0; max-width: 0;}
    2% { opacity: 0; max-width: 0; transform: translateY(-30px); }
    5% { opacity: 1; max-width: 200px; transform: translateY(5px);}
    17% { opacity: 1; max-width: 200px; transform: translateY(5px); }
    20% { opacity: 0; max-width: 0; transform: translateY(30px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; max-width: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; max-width: 0; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .rw-sentence { font-size: 18px; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
    .rw-sentence { font-size: 9px; }
}
```

It’s a little bit hacky, but it works! No JS required.

I removed the `position: absolute` and added `max-width` to the animation. Presto!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm tinkering with the codepen a little bit because I was hoping the animating word would be evenly positioned in sentence vertically and horizontally. It looks to be a little below the rest of the sentence and there's extra spacing to the right. Any ideas?

Comment: @hgwhittle yeah, so the problem actually has to do with `inline-block`, which has some [strange quirks](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). Removing the spaces between spans seems to have fixed it... I updated the CodePen. Does that look right to you?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses JavaScript:

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5dLdgor/1/)**

Here's the code that runs it:

**JavaScript**

```
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('.rw-words span'),
    maxwidth = 0,
    words = document.querySelector('.rw-words');
for (var i=0,l=spans.length;i<l;i++){
    console.log(i + ' width: ' + spans[i].offsetWidth)
    maxwidth = spans[i].offsetWidth > maxwidth ? spans[i].offsetWidth : maxwidth;
}
words.style.width = maxwidth + 'px'
```

**CSS**

```
.rw-words{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-indent: 2px;
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's some much cleaner JavaScript that achieves the same thing:

```
var spans = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.rw-words span')),
    words = document.querySelector('.rw-words'),
    maxwidth = Math.max.apply(null, spans.map(function (item) {
       return item.offsetWidth;
    }));
words.style.width = maxwidth + 'px'
```

Comment: It would be cleaner if words were centered

Comment: @Moogs – Maybe, but that's the asker's prerogative.  It's a trivial fix.  Just set the width of all spans to the maxwidth and add a `text-align: center` rule to `.rw-words span`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to really address the OP's problem at all... Shouldn't it change the width of the space to match the word? Maybe I misunderstand the question.

Comment: @TimothyMiller – That's, again, a design choice.  I personally wouldn't be jiggling the second part of the sentence around as it's not only visually distracting from the content he's trying to draw attention to (the animated words), but it also creates eye-tracking problems and potential content problems for surrounding elements.

Comment: @JoshBurgess agreed, but I thought the whole point of this question was that he *made* that choice, and was asking how to do it. But maybe I'm misunderstanding. If you're right then this is a good solution!

Comment: @TimothyMiller – Hadn't seen anything about it flowing in text naturally.  Regardless, fixes are fixes and he has options.  I'd clean up the spacing and animation issues for yours, probably drop the `text-indent` and any other `margin` or `padding` rules to get rid of that jerkiness.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width to the width of the largest element

```
var rwWords = document.querySelector('.rw-words-1');

var largest = [].slice.call(rwWords.querySelectorAll('span')).reduce(function (acc, el) {
    var len = el.textContent.trim().length;
    var cur = acc.textContent.trim().length;
    return len > cur ? el : acc;
});

rwWords.style.width = window.getComputedStyle(largest).width;
```

and center the words with

```
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
```

**JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e697j5p2/1/**